# Spring MVC + Bootstrap file upload

Tags: java, spring, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, spring-mvc

After integrating Spring MVC and Bootstrap cannot upload files. 
This Jsp page provide input field and file upload field:

```
<form:form  id="send" action="newEvent.html" method="post" commandName="event" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="form-group">
      <form:label for="inputName" path="eventName">Event name</form:label>
      <form:input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" path="eventName"/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <form:label path= "image" for="inputImage">Image</form:label>
      <form:input path= "image" class="uploadImage" id="uploadImage" type="file" name="myPhoto" onchange="PreviewImage();" />
   </div>
...........
```

Enctype set as multipart/form-data and when I integrate it with Bootsrap such post data you can see in the Post Payload and my contoller does not support such syntax :

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryPw1DcA79r6nvj3cl
>       Content-Disposition: form-data; name="eventName"
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryPw1DcA79r6nvj3cl Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="" Content-Type:
>   application/octet-stream

Without multipart/form-data it acts default way posting result strings. But it don't support to send files. What is the best way to solve this problem? Controller code below. It worked before integration as it were regular Post results.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "newEvent.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processRegistration(@ModelAttribute("event") Event event,
                                      Principal principal, Map<String, Object> model,
                                      @RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file)
                                      throws IOException {
```

At [Spring Bootstrap showcase](https://github.com/priyatam/springmvc-bootstrap) there are two separate jsp pages and controllers: one handles file upload and another spring input form.

Multi part config in Spring xml:

```
  <bean id="multipartResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
       <!-- the maximum file size in bytes -->
      <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: So you can't upload file? Does it return error or just doesn't upload file?

Comment: with multipart/form-data - Bad request error, without - No multipart request exception.

Comment: Did you configure multi part? If so can you show the code where this happens.

Comment: added Spring dispatcher xml config

Comment: Btw do you have the commons-file upload library in your pom/gradle whatever you use (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/)

Comment: Yes for sure. The key moment that without Bootstrap this upload form worked...